# Instruçao PHP para um select group by com having

Tags: php

Preciso fazer uma comparação de valores e recuperar os dados entre duas tabelas.

É um sistema de bingo a moda antiga, apenas as cartelas serão online, o sorteio será na base do globo, por bolas chamadas.

Sistema:

- O usuário entra no site e após login, prepara sua cartela virtual escolhendo 18 dezenas de 60 (entre 01 e 60).

Problema:

- A bola sorteada terá um valor entre 01 e 60, a cartela tem 18 palpites aleatórios escolhido pelo usuário.
- preciso encontrar a combinação e recupererar os dados:

Modelo de Dados:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cartela` (
  `numero_cartela` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nro_da_sorte` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numero_whats` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_indicador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `whats_indicador` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_base` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome_indicador` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numero_sorteio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numero_cartela`),
  KEY `fk_cartela_sorteio1_idx` (`numero_sorteio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `cartela` (`numero_cartela`, `nro_da_sorte`, `user_id`, `nome`, `numero_whats`, `id_indicador`, `whats_indicador`, `id_base`, `nome_indicador`, `numero_sorteio`) VALUES
(2, 123456, 7, 'andsoave', '41984009859', 7, '41984009859', 62, 'anderson', 1);

ALTER TABLE `cartela`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cartela_sorteio1` FOREIGN KEY (`numero_sorteio`) REFERENCES `sorteio` (`numero_sorteio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cartela_bola` (
  `idcartela_bola` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero_bola` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_cartela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_sorteio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcartela_bola`),
  KEY `fk_cartela_bola_cartela_idx` (`numero_cartela`),
  KEY `fk_cartela_bola_sorteio1_idx` (`numero_sorteio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `cartela_bola` (`idcartela_bola`, `numero_bola`, `numero_cartela`, `numero_sorteio`) VALUES
(2, 1, 2, 1),
(3, 2, 2, 1),
(4, 3, 2, 1);

ALTER TABLE `cartela_bola`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cartela_bola_cartela` FOREIGN KEY (`numero_cartela`) REFERENCES `cartela` (`numero_cartela`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cartela_bola_sorteio1` FOREIGN KEY (`numero_sorteio`) REFERENCES `sorteio` (`numero_sorteio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sorteio` (
  `numero_sorteio` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numero_sorteio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-

INSERT INTO `sorteio` (`numero_sorteio`, `data`, `hora`) VALUES
(1, '15/09/2018', '10:00');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sorteio_bola` (
  `idsorteio_bola` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomero_bola` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_sorteio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsorteio_bola`),
  KEY `fk_sorteio_bola_sorteio1_idx` (`numero_sorteio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `sorteio_bola` (`idsorteio_bola`, `nomero_bola`, `numero_sorteio`) VALUES
(4, 1, 1),
(5, 2, 1),
(6, 3, 1);

ALTER TABLE `sorteio_bola`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sorteio_bola_sorteio1` FOREIGN KEY (`numero_sorteio`) REFERENCES `sorteio` (`numero_sorteio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Deixei os INSERTS para servir como exemplo apenas.

SQL:

```
select c.numero_sorteio,c.numero_cartela,count(c.nomero_bola)
from   cartela_bola c,sorteio_bola select
where  c.numero_sorteio = s.numero_sorteio
and    c.nomero_bola = s.nomero_bola
group by c.numero_sorteio,c.numero_cartela
having count(c.nomero_bola) >= 16
```

Minha dificuldade:

Diante desses dados, tenho que buscar os valores das cartelas acertadoras, para salvar em outra tabela e como disse anteriormente,
não estou sabendo como executar essa instrução no PHP e MySQL.

Precisava  um exemplo para seguir, alguém pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: Só pra eu entender se é isso mesmo, você já montou as tabelas antes de saber como vai buscar os dados?

Comment: sim. achei que a idéia do group by com having, mas não estou conseguindo criar  a instrução do php